# Override $container-max-widths in vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I wont to override the default behavior of the container max widths.

This is not working :(

```
$container-max-widths: (
    'lg': 748px,
    'xl': 1440px
);
```

have anyone a working example?

Answer (score 3):

i'm facing the same problem and very new to sass, through reading
sass doc: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables
vuetify: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables

below 2 settings works for me, the first option need put important in the end,
the second option don't need but take very long time to compile.

option 1, add separate scss , it's not override vuetify sass variable, but you can read them, and apply your own logic 
add src/styles/index.scss , import the file where you need in your code

```
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
@media only screen and (min-width: map-get($grid-breakpoints, 'lg')) {
.container {
max-width: 748px !important;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: map-get($grid-breakpoints, 'xl')) {
.container {
max-width: 1440px !important;
}
}
```

need put !important; to the end to override default vuetify compiled css.

option 2, write /src/sass/variables.scss, when webpack compile, it will auto pickup the file, so you can override the global setting in proper way, but looks any change in the code will recompile all style, it took very long time for each compile and build

```
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';

$container-max-widths: (
    'lg': 748px,
    'xl': 1440px
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case all I did is add the css code in `assets/variable.css`

```css
$container-max-widths: (
    'lg': 748px,
    'xl': 1440px
);
```

and then added `treeShake: true,` in the `nuxt.config.js` in `vuetify` config

My `nuxt.config.js` looks like this:

```js
export default {
    ...

    vuetify: {
        customVariables: ["~/assets/variables.scss"],
        treeShake: true, // <-- add this line
    },
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Why do we need to use `treeShake` for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is **similar** to the answer above. This is an addition. Maybe it is **more convenient** approach

```
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/settings/variables';

@media #{map-get($display-breakpoints, 'xl-only')} {
    .container {
        max-width: 1540px !important;
    }
}
```